# How to use a button from common component as a href and with onClick event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react.I have a scenario - To use one common popup.

CommonPopup.js

```
 <ButtonWrapper>
      <Button secondary onClick={props.onRequestYes}>Yes</Button>
      <Button onClick={props.onRequestNo}>No</Button>
 </ButtonWrapper>
```

Now I need to used this common popup in two different components.

Component 1 - Use the popup and call the parent component function and do some action which is working fine.

```
 <CommonPopup           
          open={this.state.showConfirmCancelOrderPrompt}
          onRequestNo={this.togglePopup}
          onRequestYes={this.props.cancelOrder}
  />
```

Component 2 - Use the popup and On Click of "Yes" button , Navigate to a URL with 
href={`${someURL}?employeeNumber=${employeeNumber}`}

> Note: Data - someURL and employeeNumber will be passed through context

How could I make use of my component in both the scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?
`<MyButton to="user" />
class MyButton extends React.Component{
    render() { return <Link to={this.props.to} />; }
}`

Comment: In this case , How will both the scenarios will get covered ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.location = <your url>` in the function called by `onClick`. That should do the trick.
Alternatively, use `window.open(<your url>)`.

Replace `<your url>` with the url you want.

Edit: Try something like this:

```
onClick={this.openUrl}
```

Then, define the function like this:

```
openUrl() {
  url = this.props.theUrl + "?employeeNumber=" + this.props.theEmployeeNumber;
  window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: I am having dynamic url ?
Could you please tell how to include this as I am getting interpolation error in this case.

Comment: I updated the post. Could you try something like that and see if it works? Also, with passed by context, do you mean through props, redux or the new context API? I assumed props for this answer...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is , 
In component 2 ,

```
<ContentContext.Consumer>
                    {({ someURL, employeeNumber }) => (
                        <CommonPopup
                            open={this.state.showConfirmCancelOrderPrompt}
                            onRequestClose={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
                            onRequestYes={() => 
                                               this.handleSearch(someURL,employeeNumber)}
                        />
                    )}
                </ContentContext.Consumer>
```

and in function :

```
handleSearch = (someURL, employeeNumber) => {
        this.props.history.push(`${someURL}?employeeNumber=${employeeNumber}`);
           };
```